# Incorrect CAPTCHA for customer login when Capcha is disabled

Tags: frontend-error, customer-login

I am getting ***incorrect CAPTCHA*** on Magento 2.3.5 p1, on the customer login page, even though the captcha is disabled for the frontend.

In the table capcha_log i see that the entries are being registered.

The only workaround I have is to disable the captcha module, but that is not a good solution if I want captcha for the backend.

Any help would be welcomed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check if you have any other Captcha module installed like MSP_ReCaptcha
if yes then check configuration for that under **Security** tab into the configuration as shown in the below screenshot

[image: Configuration for MSP reCaptcha]

Comment: Thank you for your post. I dont have any other Captcha module installed.

Comment: MSP_ReCaptcha comes default kindly check configuration for that

Comment: I dont have the path msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled in the config table.

Comment: Adding path msp_securitysuite_recaptcha/frontend/enabled in the config table with value 0, does not solve the issue either.